# How can I remove this space between elements?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I working on my web project using bootstrap 3.3.7

Here is my HTML code example:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default nobottommargin" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-9">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</nav>

<iframe src="https://www.news.sky.com" style="width:100%;height:100%" frameborder="3"></iframe>
```

And here is working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/28825/).

As you can see in the example, there are some space between navbar and frame.

How can I remove this space? And how can I make iframe element close to navbar?

Comment: `nav-bar` is having `margin-bottom:20px` you need to add `margin-bottom:0` to the class `nobottommargin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not good practice to change predefined bootstrap styles, even using `!important`.

You just need to set negative margin-top for iframe:

```
iframe {
   margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Comment: Because .navbar css was created regarding specific reason, and changing  it can affect another elements positioning unexpectedly depending on context. Imagine if you use the same style for different pages, and some of them do not contain iframe.

Comment: In my opinion, this is the wrong answer. This only fixes the issue for the single page and if an `<iframe>` is included. In all other cases, you need to add more stylesheets to adjust the margin. I think also, it is not a good practice to adjust bootstrap styles directly. Therefor, simply use your already defined `.nobottommargin`. Btw, Bootstrap 4 has a lot of utitlity stuff like `mb-0`.

Comment: @MarcScheib your note has a sense, but anyway it depends on context and finally OP has to decide what solution most acceptable. Maybe _in all other cases_ he won't need to set this ajustment. I think that best is to define special class with negative top margin. It looks like "mirror" of your solution :)

Answer (score 4):

`.navbar` has a `margin-bottom: 20px;`. Simply remove this with an own CSS class:

```
.nobottommargin {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nav tag has set bottom margin add to nav style margin-bottom: 0px and it's should work

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default nobottommargin" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0px">
```

Answer (score 1):

In your fiddle you have added the class `nobottommargin` to your navbar, if you then add some custom CSS to your html as below you will see the margin disappears.

```
.nobottommargin {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to remove `margin-bottom` of bootstrap with custom CSS

```css
.nobottommargin {
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default nobottommargin" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-9">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>

<iframe src="https://www.news.sky.com" style="width:100%;height:100%" frameborder="3"></iframe>
```